# Merge when date is within a date range in another dataset in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, join, merge

I have 2 datasets: A and B

dataset A:

```
Date        | Age 
_____________________
31/3/2015   | 21
31/8/2015   | 30
```

dataset B:

```
StartDate   | Income
_____________________
30/3/2015   | 1k
31/7/2015   | 2k
1/10/2015   | 3k
```

How do I merge dataset A and B (left join B) so that for example, date 31/8/2015 from dataset A is within the date range of 31/7/2016 and 1/10/2015 in dataset B. So on the 31/8/2015, income would be 2k.

End result should look like this:

```
Date        | Age  | Income
__________________________________________
31/3/2015   | 21   | 1k
31/8/2015   | 30   | 2k
```

Comment: Please, [tag your DBMS.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a correlated subquery is one way to do what you want.  In standard SQL, this look like:

```
select a.*,
       (select b.income
        from b
        where b.date <= a.date
        order by b.date desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as income
from a;
```

Note:  Not all databases support the `fetch first` clause.  All support similar functionality, using `limit`, `select top` or something similar.

You can take a different approach if you like as well.  If the second table had *ranges* where the income were know rather than a single date, then you could use a join:

```
select a.*, b.income
from a left join
     (select b.*, lead(date) over (order by date) as next_date
      from b
     ) b
     on b.date <= a.date and
        (b.next_date is null or b.next_date > a.date);
```

This approach has the advantage that it is easier to fetch multiple columns from `b`.

Answer (score 1):

You need record from A and latest but minimum than A's date from Table B.

You can use the analytical function as fllows:

```
select * from
(select a.*, B.*,
       row_number() over (partition by a.date order by b.start_date desc) as rn
  from tablea a join tableb b on a.date > b.start_date) t
where rn = 1
```

**-- Update**

I think you want the record and next record from B and then compare it with A then you can use the `LEAD` as follows:

```
select a.*, b.start_date, b.income
  from tablea a 
  join (select b.*, lead(start_date) over (order by start_date) as end_Date 
          from tableb b) b 
    on a.date between b.start_Date and b.end_date 
    or (a.date > b.start_date and b.end_Date is null)
```

Comment: You can use `default` argument of `lead` to set it to infinity like `lead(start_date, 1, date '9999-12-31')` and remove `OR` condition. Also only one end of the interval should be included (I prefer `start_date`), because for `between` you'll have two output values for `date = start_date` of some interval.